# How to get compiled meteor css bundle on server side

Tags: meteor

I have multiple scss stylesheets in client/ directory. I have one particular page that is being rendered server-side and being served statically without Meteor app (it is email unsubscription confirmation).

I want to load my main site css bundle on this page.

For this objective everything I need is just a text contents of this bundle or even better an absolute path. Problem is, Assets.getText() access only private/ directory.

However, Meteor knows about this bundle file path on server side as it serves it with index.html somehow.

Is there a way to do it by myself?

Comment: From the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp): `CSS and HTML files outside special directories are loaded on the client only, and cannot be used from server code.` So, no, I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, from looking through https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/webapp/webapp_server.js, I can get mine like this:

```
path.join(
  path.dirname(
    path.join(
      __meteor_bootstrap__.serverDir,
      __meteor_bootstrap__.configJson.clientPaths['web.browser']
    )
  ),
  "merged-stylesheets.css"
)
```

on the server side.  Change `web.browser` to `web.cordova` for the mobile version.

But if you want to include it on the static page, you can probably also just go like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/merged-stylesheets.css">
```

depending on how you are serving the static page

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer only works in development.  In production the css filename is a hash, e.g. `facc2661135083eeff000051c65e72e2ad910050.css` instead of `merged-stylesheets.css`.

This works for me in development AND production:

```js
let cssPath = __meteor_bootstrap__.serverDir.replace('/server','/web.browser');
cssPath += "/"+fs.readdirSync(cssPath).find(file => file.slice(-4)==".css");
```

FYI, I'm using this server-side to pre-render with above-the-fold css: https://forums.meteor.com/t/pre-rendered-landing-pages-with-critical-css/50626